# App fails to find unmanaged dll when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll, unmanaged

I am running a Web API Asp.Net 4.6 app running in Any CPU mode (though I've also tried this specifying x64) and it makes a call to an unmanaged x64 C dll. This works fine when running within Visual Studio (using default IIS Express settings) though I get Windows Error 126 (The specified module could not be found.) when I deploy to another server and run in IIS or IIS Express even though I am sure that the path to the DLL is correct. Is there something else I can try?

My Native Methods Wrapper:

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern uint GetLastError();
}
```

My Load DLL Method:

```
private static void LoadDll()
    {
        UnloadDLL(); //Unload the module first

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DllDirectory))
            throw new ApplicationException("DPI DLL directory not specified.");

        if (!File.Exists(DllPath))
            throw new ApplicationException("Could not find DPI DLL.");

        pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(DllPath);
        //Fails Here
        if (pDll == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Failed to load library <{0}> (ErrorCode: {1})", DllPath, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error())); 
    }
```

Let me know if I can make anything else more clear, thanks!

Comment: Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to get the list of module's dependencies (module with path DllPath). Also check do you need install Visual C++ Redistributable on the server.

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan Thank you!! I've used Dependency Walker in the past but didn't think to use it here. It turned out that the DLL was compiled in debug mode and looking for debug versions of the DLL which obviously weren't on the production server. If you'd like to repost as the answer, I'd gladly accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to get the list of module's dependencies (module with path DllPath). Also check do you need install Visual C++ Redistributable on the server.

By **ikenread**: Need to check unmanaged DLL compilation mode. If it compiled in Debug mode, it will be dependent on Debug versions of Visual C++ Redistributable dlls and they will be absent (most likely) on the production server.